# Python: Need help placing a list of numbers into the lower triangle of square matrix (example provided)

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Example:

given a random list, say `a1 = [1.5]`, or `a2=[2,3,-1]`, or `a3=[5,6,7,2,3,1]`

How can you fill the lower triangle of a corresponding matrix, like so...

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

to

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  -1.,  1.]])
```

or,

```
array([[ 1.,0.],
       [ 0, 1.]])
```

to

```
array([[ 1.,0.],
       [ 1.5, 1.]])
```

I tried several times to solve this problem but my code is very complicated and ultimately wrong. Even worse I can't paste the code without getting an error saying my formatting is wrong. Here is a picture of part of the code.

I can't post a picture because I dont have the needed reputation points.

CODE WORKS NOW! Look below!

```
# n is the length of your list (i.e. n =len(numbers))
for j in range(n-1):
    for i in range(1+j,n):
    matrix[i][j]=numbers.pop(0)
```

Comment: I think maybe `total = [4, 3, 2]` should be `numbers = [4, 3, 2]`, at least judging by the desired result.

Comment: OP here. I got distracted by a minor issue. My updated code is below.

Comment: ['code'] numbers = [4,5,6]

size = n

matrix = numpy.eye(size)

j,k=numpy.triu_indices(size)

diag_entries = j==k

j = j[~diag_entries]
k = k[~diag_entries]

the_list = numbers

matrix[i, j] = the_list

Comment: I re-wrote my question so it is easier to get at. Please read.

Comment: I see you have now removed your code.  So: the question does not show you have made any effort to solve it.

Comment: I got this to work all!

Comment: `# n is the length of your list (i.e. n =len(numbers))

for j in range(n-1):
  for i in range(1+j,n):
    matrix[i][j]=numbers.pop(0)'

Comment: but I still dont know how to paste code....

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy.tril_indices` or `numpy.triu_indices`, depending on how you want to order the entries. The following example will additionally take care not to set diagonal entries:

```
import numpy as np
size = 4

m = np.eye(size)  # identity matrix
j, i = np.triu_indices(size, 1)

the_list = np.arange(size * (size - 1) / 2)[::-1] + 1  # The list of entries
print the_list  # yields [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

# Set the entries
m[i, j] = the_list 

print m
# yields
# array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 6.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 5.,  3.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 4.,  2.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Note that if you want to set in line order, you can use `i, j = np.tril_indices(size, -1)`. If you would like to set the diagonal as well, then remove the second argument in `np.triu_indices`.

Comment: 'np.tril_indices` takes a second argument, the diagonal offset. For the OP's case he can simply do: `m[np.tril_indices(m.shape[0], -1)] = the_list`.

Comment: Instead of generating a list, how would you adjust your code for a given list of numbers? (i.e. list is [4,8,7] and you want a matrix of form [[1,0,0],[4,1,0],[8,7,1]]

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, I had completely overlooked that argument. Will make the example nicer.

Comment: @user3373665 you mean guess the matrix shape from the length of the list? That only works when the length of the list is of the form `n * (n - 1) / 2`. If the list length is different, you could go to the next larger size, sure, but how would you place the elements?